# Neo4j doesn't obey my database location setting

Tags: configuration, neo4j

When open up the Neo4j Community Edition program, it gives me an option to choose my database location.

[image]

I chose the path `D:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j`.

When I look at the database information in the browser, I find that this is not where the database is actually located.

[image]

It seems to ignore my choice and always put the database in `C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb`. Is there a way I can actually change the database location?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and it worked for me.
I chose the new directory directly after install though. But also after choosing a different directory it honored my selection.

Did you have an old installation or a fresh install?

[image]